# Setting NAs based on time-series gaps

Tags: r

In this dataset I'm working with, there should be a GPS point taken every hour. Sometimes that doesn't happen. For instance, if a point is taken at 7:35:00, and then at 9:35:50, that's missing a point at 8:35:00. Sometimes it doesn't always take EXACTLY at the hour (it's normal to be a minute or two off).

So, I want the code to find one of those gaps, and then fill it in with NA and assign the time variable to be exactly one hour from the time before it. So, in that example, the time would be 7:35:00 + 1 hour which is 8:35:00.

Can someone please help me do this? Thanks! It doesn't necessarily have to use the function setNA.

```
date.ref <- as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")

data_ade <- setNA(ltraj = as.ltraj(xy = MALLfixgap[, c("easting", "northing")], 
                                   date = MALLfixgap$time, 
                                   id = MALLfixgap$ID), 
                  date.ref, 
                  dt = 60, units = "min")

# Transform back to dataframe
data_na <- ld(data_ade)[, c("id", "x", "y", "date")]
colnames(data_na) <- c("ID", "x", "y", "time")
```

Here is my dataframe:

```
> dput(head(MALLfixgap, n = 100))
structure(list(ID = c("2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", "2247-80403", 
"2247-80403", "2247-80403"), easting = c(4789877.79486812, 4789883.22338805, 
4789872.6990871, 4789884.14733088, 4789863.39341927, 4789861.1929318, 
4789879.88205765, 4789865.88296564, 4789867.96720017, 4789865.4193077, 
4789862.21809361, 4789857.52892821, 4790025.67824367, 4789988.56330436, 
4789929.21308679, 4789947.30654742, 4789938.61833214, 4789941.3559971, 
4788632.64545618, 4788625.5602232, 4788630.77756288, 4788643.64612259, 
4788893.95795771, 4788882.34742438, 4788859.91463275, 4788852.66919723, 
4788869.20634467, 4788871.43758427, 4788877.6597533, 4788844.59942807, 
4788845.94577376, 4788854.91406404, 4788850.2162095, 4788837.30670172, 
4788830.33142545, 4788847.98152952, 4788866.13684693, 4788909.54925369, 
4788850.1958688, 4788867.95115174, 4788962.87762379, 4788882.42833551, 
4788835.24397643, 4788823.03163673, 4788865.1137122, 4788880.39616727, 
4788873.13390209, 4788865.33591725, 4788848.37846144, 4788845.88830888, 
4788860.7998954, 4788864.21911175, 4788865.3867541, 4788860.03269426, 
4788883.75121846, 4788900.18671298, 4788829.05896354, 4788839.21838332, 
4788859.98537291, 4788840.26139994, 4788865.35978687, 4788884.95249518, 
4788884.27995754, 4788905.89869893, 4788932.92090071, 4788873.42426034, 
4788871.10484433, 4788891.51879251, 4788880.15113053, 4788884.04167358, 
4788874.10686787, 4788884.32732493, 4788846.12446164, 4788875.94294222, 
4788885.82407131, 4788885.11439084, 4788844.00780938, 4788819.5416904, 
4788885.42719643, 4788873.56794312, 4788826.57552012, 4788866.96812912, 
4788881.60404111, 4788827.80539188, 4788832.17750795, 4788878.23694285, 
4788887.77717336, 4788864.06166938, 4788871.72789858, 4788892.27400588, 
4788874.96474922, 4788869.3784384, 4788897.85901981, 4788873.75334305, 
4788850.33431453, 4788868.22457824, 4788845.35421448, 4788841.62577823, 
4788863.19715801, 4788866.61589812), northing = c(464654.773882482, 
464657.31827309, 464652.312386292, 464650.505230673, 464647.880989663, 
464665.238880783, 464659.16766409, 464660.312229297, 464665.274157322, 
464664.043411924, 464702.986035201, 464622.445708964, 464641.908790647, 
464688.790319358, 464612.349244445, 464635.331909526, 464682.930063078, 
464647.719026793, 464417.899935188, 464392.453443051, 464435.262658188, 
464416.739901817, 463005.978714995, 463037.493382926, 463037.37122236, 
463042.28359997, 463023.784018041, 463021.92909336, 463041.77025241, 
463035.420734791, 463032.911558778, 463017.536663393, 463023.680566933, 
463049.018886662, 463004.333087346, 463046.560491778, 463057.21240023, 
463018.402584567, 463027.414627095, 463029.946663919, 463096.135312284, 
463022.638387991, 463040.321632375, 463039.605710959, 463081.965951549, 
463008.340117455, 463016.337097127, 463041.134907112, 463055.24866093, 
463043.464344044, 463017.568732526, 463021.8897678, 463031.799777642, 
463015.697469583, 463004.056008921, 463024.602204387, 463013.661608763, 
463024.270077157, 463024.383205721, 463057.071568184, 463036.751455015, 
463028.172189735, 462988.554040265, 462975.034192797, 463009.275787805, 
462963.086331485, 463001.470580211, 462984.859363954, 462971.809006551, 
462950.805325981, 462980.462010126, 462979.868334933, 463000.116749105, 
463112.385165291, 463010.886192563, 462998.462210994, 463001.322876701, 
463048.272752641, 463002.198068046, 463018.206541197, 463000.659609786, 
463047.313278951, 463010.86319526, 462938.078145919, 462910.25801047, 
462935.918193438, 462958.212840609, 462969.285909443, 462968.67831468, 
462927.877129635, 462986.067925645, 462992.206945394, 462983.026867228, 
462984.194240411, 463002.006782918, 462979.78050861, 462978.438105836, 
462969.731751458, 462964.897608712, 462969.29984443), time = structure(c(1675730993, 
1675734585, 1675738235, 1675741809, 1675745417, 1675749019, 1675752633, 
1675756224, 1675759835, 1675763419, 1675767019, 1675770614, 1675774215, 
1675777840, 1675781483, 1675785065, 1675788667, 1675792293, 1675795859, 
1675799458, 1675803059, 1675806659, 1675810260, 1675813865, 1675817474, 
1675821059, 1675824741, 1675828341, 1675831939, 1675835555, 1675839139, 
1675842744, 1675846339, 1675849939, 1675853564, 1675857144, 1675860764, 
1675864355, 1675867965, 1675871579, 1675875148, 1675878757, 1675882349, 
1675885969, 1675889569, 1675893173, 1675896765, 1675900385, 1675903948, 
1675907545, 1675911156, 1675914779, 1675918364, 1675921956, 1675925565, 
1675929154, 1675932756, 1675936379, 1675939960, 1675943555, 1675947179, 
1675950755, 1675954348, 1675957953, 1675961556, 1675965164, 1675968766, 
1675972379, 1675975965, 1675979579, 1675983159, 1675986753, 1675990348, 
1675993947, 1675997561, 1676001149, 1676004757, 1676008351, 1676011956, 
1676015549, 1676019156, 1676022749, 1676026349, 1676029950, 1676033558, 
1676037164, 1676040779, 1676044364, 1676047964, 1676051579, 1676055157, 
1676058758, 1676062365, 1676065964, 1676069564, 1676073180, 1676076757, 
1676080354, 1676083979, 1676087579), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "GMT")), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I appreciate all help.

Comment: Are such errors present in the dataframe that you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You might try package `{zoo}` to achieve your goal. Notice that your data is named `xyzzy` in this example.

```r
> xyzzy = xyzzy[-c(4, 7), ] 
> xyzzy$time_merge = round(xyzzy$time, "hour")
> library(zoo)
> xyzzy = merge(read.zoo(xyzzy, index.column = "time_merge"), 
+               zoo(, seq(min(xyzzy$time_merge), max(xyzzy$time_merge), "hour"))) 
> head(xyzzy, n = 8)
                    ID         easting northing time               
2023-02-07 01:00:00 2247-80403 4789878 464654.8 2023-02-07 00:49:53
2023-02-07 02:00:00 2247-80403 4789883 464657.3 2023-02-07 01:49:45
2023-02-07 03:00:00 2247-80403 4789873 464652.3 2023-02-07 02:50:35
2023-02-07 04:00:00 <NA>       <NA>    <NA>     <NA>               
2023-02-07 05:00:00 2247-80403 4789863 464647.9 2023-02-07 04:50:17
2023-02-07 06:00:00 2247-80403 4789861 464665.2 2023-02-07 05:50:19
2023-02-07 07:00:00 <NA>       <NA>    <NA>     <NA>               
2023-02-07 08:00:00 2247-80403 4789866 464660.3 2023-02-07 07:50:24
```

**(1)** Remove the rows 4 and 7 (`c(4, 7)`) to simulate your issue.
**(2)** Round the datetime by `"hour"`, and create a new datetime column (`time_merge`) to merge on.
**(3)** Make the original data a *zoo-object*: `read.zoo(xyzzy, index.column = "time_merge")`, where the column containig the datetime information is specified. Create an artifical time series based on min and max of `xyzzy$time_merge` without data. `merge.zoo` the two *zoo-objects*.

---

If you like to fake the data, you can do something like this:

```r
> xyzzy = as.data.frame(xyzzy)
> xyzzy$time_merge = rownames(xyzzy)
> rownames(xyzzy) = NULL
> # new = 
> within(xyzzy, {
+   time_merge = as.POSIXct(time_merge, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
+   time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
+   time[is.na(time)] = 
+     as.POSIXct(paste(format(time_merge[is.na(time)] - 60, "%Y-%m-%d %H"), 
+                      sample(48:52, 1), sample(00:59, 1), sep = ":"), tz = "GMT")
+   # time_merge = NULL
+ })
            ID easting northing                time          time_merge
1   2247-80403 4789878 464654.8 2023-02-07 00:49:53 2023-02-07 01:00:00
2   2247-80403 4789883 464657.3 2023-02-07 01:49:45 2023-02-07 02:00:00
3   2247-80403 4789873 464652.3 2023-02-07 02:50:35 2023-02-07 03:00:00
4         <NA>    <NA>     <NA> 2023-02-07 03:49:21 2023-02-07 04:00:00
5   2247-80403 4789863 464647.9 2023-02-07 04:50:17 2023-02-07 05:00:00
6   2247-80403 4789861 464665.2 2023-02-07 05:50:19 2023-02-07 06:00:00
7         <NA>    <NA>     <NA> 2023-02-07 06:49:21 2023-02-07 07:00:00
8   2247-80403 4789866 464660.3 2023-02-07 07:50:24 2023-02-07 08:00:00
```

Haven't thought about this carefully; code can certainly be written cleaner.

Comment: Hey @Friede! thanks for the response. I do want to keep the minutes there. Could I round by minutes instead?

Comment: Let me know what's missing.